# why html table have multiple column's data into one column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to have a html table with `scrollbar`, I made one scrollable table example but the problem is all the column data are fit into one column, as show in here.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/bqtzykuj/4/

in this example, the css is

```
<tbody style="height: 350px; max-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;display:block;">
```

However if I remove the `display:block`, the previously described problem disappeared, but the scrollable bar also disappear.  http://jsfiddle.net/bqtzykuj/5/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: block;` to `thead` as well. it will work.

Check here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3x27f6by/

Working snippet here:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead {
  display: block;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="text-warning">
    <th>price</th>
    <th>amount</th>
    <th>total</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="height: 350px; max-height: 400px;overflow-y:auto; display:block;">

    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr _ngcontent-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <td _ngcontent-c14="" style="color:red;">0.002078 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">12354.572620 </td>
      <td _ngcontent-c14="">25.677144 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Added below style to `th` and `td` to look it better:

```
th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: block;` use `display: table-row-group;`

In order for the elements to function/display as a table:

- Table cells `<td>` require the parent to be `display: table;` or `display: table-cell;`
- This also applies to Table rows `<tr>` which require the parent to be `display:table;` or `display:table-row-group;`

In your case you're changing the parent of `<tr>` to `display:block;` which then means the child `<tr>` nodes will not render in the correct table format as the parent is not `display: table;` or `display: table-row-group;`